# How to add a list of entities and How can I get Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, addrange

I have a problem with Entity Framework in Asp.net mvc . I want to get the Id value whenever I add a list of entities to database. How can I do this?

i use this code for add a list of entities to database :

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> AddThisRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
{
  return ((DbSet<TEntity>)this.Set<TEntity>()).AddRange(entities);
}


var Tags = _uow.AddThisRange(newTags.Select(tagName => new Tag
{
 //set properties
}));

 _uow.SaveAllChanges();

foreach (var tag in Tags)
{
   var id = tag.Id;// id always is 0
}
```

i using DB generated Ids (like IDENTITY in MS SQL)

Comment: Have you tested fetching the Tags from the db after the AddThisRange-call and then checking what the id's are?

Comment: yes.ID's created in the database.

Comment: So thats the solution :)

Comment: so why tag.Id always is 0 ? how can reload that ?

Comment: So what I'm trying to say is that since the id's are created in the database when you save the tags, you have to fetch them from the database again after saving before you can use the id's in your code.

Comment: so why tag.Id always is 0 ? --> Because of select new Tag(). See my answer

Answer (score 3):

I think the "problem" is that the id's are generated in the database. You have to first save the Tags, then fetch them again before you can use their id's in your code.

Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> AddThisRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : class
{
  return ((DbSet<TEntity>)this.Set<TEntity>()).AddRange(entities);
}


var Tags = _uow.AddThisRange(newTags.Select(tagName => new Tag
{
 //set properties
}));

 _uow.SaveAllChanges();

//Pseudocode:
var savedTags = _uow.GetSavedTags(newTags);

foreach (var tag in savedTags)
{
   var id = tag.Id;// id will not be 0 anymore
}
```

Comment: what is GetSavedTags?

Comment: Thats pseudocode for getting the tags from the database. I guess something similar exists in OP's code.

Comment: see my answer the problem is in the [ Select(new Tag...]. no need to reload data fromDB

Comment: Yeah, you actually don't need to reload the data.  The `Id` will already be updated by Entity Framework automatically. `Tags` can be iterated directly, instead of `savedTags`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public TEntity Create<TEntity>()
{
   return ((DbSet<TEntity>)this.Set<TEntity>()).Create();
}

var listOfEntities =new List<Tag>();
foreach (var d in newTags)
{
    var entity = _uow.Create<Tag>();
    //set properties        
    //entity.prop=""
    listOfEntities.Add(entity);
}
_uow.AddThisRange(listOfEntities);
_uow.SaveAllChanges();
```

and then you can see the Id values has setted in your list

```
foreach (var tag in listOfEntities)
{
   var id = tag.Id;
}
```

you can read this article what create method is do https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696136(v=vs.113).aspx